# Why namespaces register a subsys_initcall doing nothing

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm new at looking at the kernel code. `namespaces.c` ([link](https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/cgroup/namespace.c.html#cgroup_namespaces_init)) has this:

```
static __init int cgroup_namespaces_init(void)
{
    return 0;
}
subsys_initcall(cgroup_namespaces_init);
```

If I understood correctly, `subsys_initcall` will make a call to that function when Linux is loading.
What is the purpose of that if `cgroup_namespaces_init` simply returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

I get the impression there isn’t any; if you want to determine this with certainty, you could submit a patch to remove it.

Comment: I would love to do that! just to go through the experience of submitting a patch... weekend task  :D